# File inclusion not working

Tags: java, java-ee-6

The below code throws an error in Netbeans saying the include statement is not closed.  I've tried a few things like `@%>` and I'm not able to figure out what's up.  what am I doing wrong here?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><%=request.getAttribute("title")%></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@include file=request.getAttribute("template")%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: file param value should be enclosed in quotes, that might be causing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`<jsp:directive.include/>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/12/syntaxref129.html#997991):

```
<jsp:directive.include file="<%= request.getAttribute("template") %>"/>
```

Depending on the contents of your template, [`<jsp:include/>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/12/syntaxref1214.html#8828) may also work:

```
<jsp:include path="<%= request.getAttribute("template") %>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The include directive works at compile time (translation time), the path listed in file should be relative to the web application.

> The include directive is processed when the JSP page is translated
>   into a servlet class. The effect of the directive is to insert the
>   text contained in another file--either static content or another JSP
>   page--in the including JSP page

if you want to use something more flexible when used to include files jstl tag **< c:import >**

> Using the jstl  we can also include those contents or files
>   which are not a part of the current web application but lying
>   somewhere outside the web application